# What exactly does the Resolve-Path cmdlet do?

Tags: powershell, path

I've started working with Powershell lately on my Windows 10 system. I've created a profile file, and I wanted to put in a variable which links to a folder in my documents section. However, I didn't want to hard-code the path because I knew I'd need to go in and re-write it if my profile name got changed in a hard drive transfer like it did the last time I sent it in for repairs. So my first thought was to put in something like this:

```
$Var = $(~\Documents\Folder)
```

But that spat back an error. Then I learned of the Resolve-Path Cmdlet, which appeared at a glance to be what I needed. However, when I did this:

```
$Var = $(Resolve-Path ~\Documents\Folder)
```

... I got this:

```
>$Var

Path
----
C:\Users\Username\Documents\Folder

>
```

Which seemed like a problem. However, when I tried to `cd $Var`, it worked successfully, which confused me greatly. I figured that the extraneous `Path` header in the result would cause an error.

What exactly does `Resolve-Path` *do*, and why does it still get interpreted correctly when passed into `cd`? And additionally, is there any way to make `Resolve-Path` *not* include the extraneous information and return only the expanded path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the header `Path` is because `Resolve-Path` is returning an object of type `System.Management.Automation.PathInfo` and when this is not captured into a variable it is outputted as a string to the console in a readable format IE:

```
 ObjProperty1      ObjProperty2      ObjProperty3  ...
 ---------         ---------         ---------     ...
 Value1            Value2            Value3        ...
```

This object works with `cd` as `PowerShell` is smart enough to parse the object (`$var`) before `cd` is run. `PowerShell` will return the value of the path property to `cd` meaning `cd` will see a string `"C:\Users\Username\Documents\Folder"` and not the object headers.

If you want to just return the path without the header use the `Select` cmdlet's `-ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
$var = Resolve-Path '~\Documents\Folder' | select -ExpandProperty Path
```

If you would like more information on `Resolve-Path` MSDN is a good place to start ([link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you! I must have missed the return type, otherwise I would've looked deeper into it. Is there any particular advantage to `select` over just saying `().Path` like the other answer said?

Comment: @BHustus no there isn't really any advantage of using ether one, as they both end up call the same retrieve command.

Answer (score 4):

Easy Example for a Resolve-Path job,

Let's say you don't know the office version in your computer and want to get the correct path, `Resolve-Path` can help...

```
$TestPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\*\Winword.exe'
$Path = (Resolve-Path $TestPath).Path
```

Comment: I didn't want to know what `Resolve-Path` was used for - I knew that already. I wanted to know why it was behaving what seemed to be oddly. But thanks for giving me an option to store the path only.

Answer (score 1):

`Resolve-Path` is a good way to find a nested file or folder with wildcards in the middle of the folder path (not just in the path's Leaf).

Best use case I've seen is, when a restore request comes into the SD and the claim is that an entire folder disappeared. Someone probably moved the folder into (under) an adjacent folder in their GUI. Easily find that folder like this:

```
PS> Resolve-Path 'folderOldLocation\*\folderName'
PS> Resolve-Path 'folderOldLocation\*\*\folderName'
PS> # Going deeper is unlikely to find it
PS> #  and will take much longer to return
```

It's a very quick way to check for a quick fix to an otherwise time-consuming restore request.

Comment: The fact that Set-Location has a parameter named path doesn't matter.
It works because Powershell does an implicit conversion of the [PathInfo] object through its ToString method...

The Path parameter does make a difference when you pipe an object with a Path property to Set-Location. Look up Powershell parameter binding...

Comment: Sorry no, this is exactly how pipelines work. I double checked because I thought I was right. I was (nothing in here about tostring method): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2#parameter-binding. I updated by answer to provide more of this detail. The ToString mthod of the incoming object is invoked if the the parameter in the pipeline-accepting function accepts a string object byValue. In the OPs case, the Path parameter matches byPropertyName so that is used.

Comment: But cd ($var) doesn't even use the pipeline!
You can see the conversion if you use the Trace-Command cmdlet.
PS > $var=$(Resolve-Path d:\da*)
PS > $var

Path
----
D:\Data

PS > Trace-Command -Name TypeConversion -Expression {cd $var} -PSHost
DEBUG: 2022-08-23 18:36:02.1883 TypeConversion Information: 0 : Converting "D:\Data" to "System.String".
DEBUG: 2022-08-23 18:36:02.2419 TypeConversion Information: 0 :     Converting object to string.
PS D:\Data> Trace-Command -Name TypeConversion -Expression {cd d:\data} -PSHost
PS D:\Data>

Note: No conversion on the last command!

Comment: Yes, you're right. OP didn't ask about pipelines. I removed that part from my answer. I originally wanted to add this use case for anyone searching this cmdlet.